# How to use React components as views in an Asp.net core 7.0 project

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to use my react components only as a view for my MVC project. The Project is already existing and react was injected to the project manually and not with the ASp.net React framework from visual studio.

I can call controller from my react front end but I do not know the other way around, how to call my front end "components" from the controller backend?

With Razor pages there are often Views() returned. how do I get the same functionality just returning my React components from my clientapp folder?

For example I want to display my already build frontend "app.js" in my clientapp folder.

I tried to put the build folder from clientapp into wwwroot.
In my cshtml file where I want to display my component I added this:

```
<div id="react-container"></div>
<script src="../clientapp/build/static/js/main.d3c946d6.js"></script>

<script>
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(MyComponent),
    document.getElementById('react-container')
  );
</script>
```

this is my component in another clientapp folder src

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return <h1>Hello from React component!</h1>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Program.cs looks like this

```
var spaPath = "/MyUrl";
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapWhen(y => y.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(spaPath), client =>
    {
        client.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("https://localhost:4444");
        });
    });
}
else
{
    app.Map(new PathString(spaPath), client =>
    {
        client.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        client.UseSpa(spa => {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "clientapp";

            // adds no-store header to index page to prevent deployment issues (prevent linking to old .js files)
            // .js and other static resources are still cached by the browser
            spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    ResponseHeaders headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                    headers.CacheControl = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue
                    {
                        NoCache = true,
                        NoStore = true,
                        MustRevalidate = true
                    };
                }
            };
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: [Does the link useful to you ?](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-React-to-existing-ASPNet-Core-Project.aspx)